# How can I achieve multi-page theorems?

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

I'm using tcolorbox theorems as following:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{example}{Example}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{x}
```

This works great and looks really good. But if I've got text in my `example` that is bigger then the actual page it keeps on printing until the edge of the page and then disappears. It would be inconvenient to split the `example` into 2 `example`s. Is there any way I can get LaTeX to automatically split these boxes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the `breakable` key to allow page breaks; this requires adding the `breakable` library, or you can load `tcolorbox` with the `many` option to load `breakable` and `theorems` libraries and some other ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{example}{Example}{
  breakable,
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}{x}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{Some example}{test}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to remove the border rule at the bottom on page breaks, add `enhanced`:

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{example}{Example}{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  colback=green!5,
  colframe=green!35!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries}{x}
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should read the manual more carefully :) Is there any way to remove the bottom border before a page break? So the reader knows that there is more on the next page.

Comment: @jreuab You're welcome. Please see my updated answer.